# bad file descriptor from fread

Tags: c, file, io, file-descriptor, file-pointer

I try to use read() to get some characters from file just for learning this API. I have create a file called "file" in the same directory and it contains 1000 characters. But I got an error saying:

```
read: %m: Bad file descriptor
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <error.h>

int read_indent(int sockfd){
  int sport, cport;
  char user[2], rtype[2], addinfo[2];
  char buffer[17];

  if(read(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer)) <= 0) {
    perror("read: %m");
    return -1;
  }

  buffer[sizeof(buffer)-1] = '\0';

  sscanf(buffer, "%d:%d:%s:%s:%s", &sport, &cport, rtype, user, addinfo);
  printf("%d:%d:%s:%s:%s", sport, cport, rtype, user, addinfo);
  return 0;
}

int main(){
  FILE *file_pt = fopen("file", "r");
  if(file_pt == NULL) { printf("fopen error\n"); return -1;}
  char buf[128];
  int a = read_indent(file_pt);
  fclose(file_pt);
  return 0;
}
```

UPDATE 1: Compilation message

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:27:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘read_indent’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
  int a = read_indent(file_pt);
  ^
test.c:4:5: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘struct FILE *’
 int read_indent(int sockfd){
```

Comment: The code you posted can not possibly compile. You're passing a `FILE*` into a function taking an `int`.

Comment: Did your compiler complained when seeing a `FILE*` being passed to where an `int^ was expected?

Comment: I posted the compilation message as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `read_indent` function takes a file descriptor, but you're passing in a `FILE*` pointer. Try turning the `FILE*` pointer into a file descriptor using `fileno`:

```
int a = read_indent(fileno(file_pt));
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is working now but I have one more question, kindly see my update. The printf is generating one garbage character and extra `::`

Comment: @dannycrane You need to make space for the null character in `char user[2]` and co, so turn that into `char user[3]`.

Comment: I make the following changes: user[3], rtype[3], addinfo[3], buf[4+4+3+3+3], now it is printing 1:2:ab:cd:ef::xPvx. What is the problem? (x is again garbage)

Comment: @dannycrane Make a new question, and make sure to post your input file contents as well.

Comment: Here it is. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051246/why-are-extra-garbage-characters-printed