# Why are extra garbage characters printed?

Tags: c, string

I try to use read() to get some characters from file just for learning this API. I have create a file called "file" in the same directory and it is content:

```
1:2:ab:cd:ef
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <error.h>

int read_indent(int sockfd){
  int sport, cport;
  char user[3], rtype[3], addinfo[3];
  char buffer[4+4+3+3+3+1];

  if(read(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer)) <= 0) {
    perror("read: %m");
    return -1;
  }

  buffer[sizeof(buffer)-1] = '\0';

  sscanf(buffer, "%d:%d:%s:%s:%s", &sport, &cport, rtype, user, addinfo);
  printf("%d:%d:%s:%s:%s", sport, cport, rtype, user, addinfo);
  return 0;
}

int main(){
  FILE *file_pt = fopen("file", "r");
  if(file_pt == NULL) { printf("fopen error\n"); return -1;}
  char buf[128];
  int a = read_indent(fileno(file_pt));
  fclose(file_pt);
  return 0;
}
```

My printf returns me

```
1:2:ab:cd:ef::xPvx
```

where `x` is some garbage character I cannot recognize. What is the reason for this? `int` is 4 bytes in my system.

Comment: Did you leave space for a trailing 0 character at the end of each string, and store it?

Comment: Could you elaborate? I thought my user[3] contains on extra character to store '\0' because my file has only `ab`. Similarly i create three entries for rtype and addinfo. I also created an extra on for the last '\0'...It is probably something basic, but I am not sure what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is that you didn't specify a width for the `%s` parameters. This means that it matches up until the first whitespace character. There are no whitespace characters in your string, so the first `%s` matches until the end, leaving only garbage data after your string to fill the other variables.

Try this:

```
sscanf(buffer, "%d:%d:%2s:%2s:%2s", &sport, &cport, rtype, user, addinfo);
```

The other issue is that you don't null-terminate your buffer properly, `read` returns the number of characters read - add a null after that.

Comment: That works nicely. If I use your line above, can I use "char user[2], rtype[2], addinfo[2];" during initialization? Because when I change to this initialization, it still prints the same output, the sscanf does not seem to add an extra '\0' for any %2s it scans in, i.e., it only fills the buffer with 2 bytes (no trailing '\0')

Comment: @dannycrane No. A string in C (`char*`) is a __memory location__. It starts at that memory location, and keeps going __until the first null character__. Your strings should be null-terminated. `%2s` does null-terminate for you automatically, for example try printing the value of `user[2]` as a `%d` and you will see it is `0`.

Comment: That makes lot of sense. I just try "char user[2], rtype[2], addinfo[2];" and "char user[3], rtype[3], addinfo[3];", both prints 0 for user[2] using %d. But if I initialize the buffer with "char user[2], rtype[2], addinfo[2];", why does user[2], rtype[2], addinfo[2] still prints 0? Since I thought the three buffers are allocated one next to each other in the stack. So at least one of the print should not print 0. My machine is 64-bit with 64-bit OS.

Comment: @dannycrane There's one very important thing you should know about C. There is no error checking the language does for you. It just silently fails, or it could crash, or it could silently fail now but crash later, or it could give bogus values.

Comment: So if my initializations are char user[2], rtype[2], addinfo[2], and the '\0' is stored somewhere outside my initialization, this will cause silent fails or crashes later. But do we know where are the three extra '\0' stored in the stack? (Thanks for answering these question, this is the last one :) )

Comment: @dannycrane We do not know. A core concept in the C language is 'undefined behaviour'. That means that anything can happen, crashing, bogus values, nothing, your disk could get formatted, etc. Accessing an array outside of its size is an example of undefined behaviour. This can happen indirectly. For example if you use `char user[2]`, and do `user[0] = user[1] = 'a';`, so that user contains 'aa'. But if you'd do `strlen(user);` then that will be undefined behaviour! Because `strlen` assumes the passed string ends with a null character it will keep going past the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
 char buffer[4+4+3+3+3+1];
```

The buffer is bigger than what you plan to read and that's ok, but:

```
 buffer[sizeof(buffer)-1] = '\0';
```

This is wrong, add the *\0* at `size+1` , where size is what you get back with `read()`, the actual number of bytes read.

See [here:](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html)

> The value returned may be less than nbyte if the number of bytes left in the file is less than nbyte, if the read() request was interrupted by a signal, or if the file is a pipe or FIFO or special file and has fewer than nbyte bytes immediately available for reading.

Comment: I dont quite understand your answer. I change to   char buffer[20]; during initialization and I use `printf("sizeof(buffer) = %lu\n", sizeof(buffer));` after   `buffer[sizeof(buffer)-1] = '\0';`. It still prints 20 as the size.

Comment: @dannycrane 'sizeof' tells you the size of the _buffer_, not the size of the string contained in it. Altering the contents of the buffer cannot change its size. The problem is not that the size of the buffer is changing; the problem is that you are putting the nul terminator (the '\0') at the end of the _buffer_, not the end of the _string_.

Comment: (Sorry for the typos here and there :) ). As @davmac said. That could be a HUGE source of bugs/vulnerabilites.

Answer (score 0):

```
char buffer[4+4+3+3+3+1];
if(read(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer)) <= 0) {
    //....
}
buffer[sizeof(buffer)-1] = '\0';
```

The read function does not add `\0` to the buffer after reading. But you read just 12 bytes, and your buffer size is 18. So you still have 5 bytes of garbage in your buffer. This gets added to the last string you read.